# Regex to allow space between char of a specific string

Tags: regex, django, string

I want to create a regex to allow space between characters of a specific string.

The context is we have a unclean database, with string that contains sometimes space where they shouldn't have. I'm not yet allow to remove the space in the database (replace(' ', '')).

I would like to have a regex to be able to match a string even if the string is cut with space.

ex:
obama would match "obama", "ob ama", " obama", " ob ama", "obam  a", but not "obamaa", "ocama", " ".

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `<space>*` inbetween each character.

```
\bo *b *a *m *a\b
```

or use `[ \t]*` in the above instead of a space.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without regular expression also

```
>>> a = "ob ama"
>>> ''.join(a.split(' ')) == 'obama'
True
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
(\S? )*\S
```

If leading spaces are a problem, this should be modified. Also, this allows multiple spaces but you didn't really say anything about that. And if you need to allow other kinds of whitespace characters besides regular space, this needs some more modification. This should handle other whitespace characters:

```
(\S?\s)*\S
```